# Bookmark level difference when using hyperref

Tags: latex, hyperref

When creating my output with miktex in texniccenter I get the following warning

```
Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater than one, level fixed on input line 3
```

Can someone explain this warning to me and perhaps give me a hint for a solution of the problem?

Comment: perhaps you could provide a minimal working example, as described at: 
http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html#x1-30002

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That message is emitted by the hyperref package. Usually it means that you've skipped a level of headings.  Something like:

```
\chapter{Chapter heading}
% skipping the \section -- bad move
\subsection{Subsection heading}
```

Check your document to make sure that you have all your headings in order and haven't skipped any in the hierarchy.

(That being said, it is only a warning, so it can be ignored if you like.)